# How to call toplinks in footer through Magento's page.xml

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am new to Magento, and I'm coming at this with the persective of a web designer experienced in configuring/designing for CMSs. So all the layout xml stuff is pretty foreign to me. I simply want to add My Account, Log In/Log Out, and My Cart links to the footer.

[This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/25803/) Magento forum post describes what code to use and what files to copy from and paste to, but for the life of me I cannot figure out exactly where in page.xml I should put the various addLink xml code to get it to show in my footer.

Here is the XML for the My Account and Log In/Out links, from customer.xml:

```
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->

    <customer_logged_out>
        <!---<reference name="right">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
        </reference>-->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>
```

Here is the XML in page.xml where the forum post says it should go, and where I'm not exactly sure what line it should go in:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>

                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>

            </block>
```

And here is the markup from footer.phtml, where the links should end up:

```
<div class="four columns">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
```

I'm also having trouble wrapping my mind around how getChildHtml, which pulls in the footer links, knows where to get those links.

Any help would be massively appreciated! As excited I am about the power of Magento, it is blowing my mind how I can spend hours on a task as seemingly simple as adding links to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,try the below code in footer

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("footer_links") ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps.

By default magento uses the "default" theme and I assume that you are using this theme. I suggest not to change the page.xml or any xml files of magento. 
1.Create a `local.xml` in `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout`.

2.Add the below code to local.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            // This code it to remove the site map, search terms, advanced search, order and returns. Remove the below 4 lines if you want these in the footer.
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /></action> 
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" /></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" /></action> 
            <remove name="return_link" />
            // to add my account link to footer links
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
            // to add cart link
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
     <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>20</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>20</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>
 </layout>
```

3.To remove contact us goto Admin panel `System > Configuration > General > Contacts` and set "Enable contact us" to no.

4.To remove the About us, Customer Service and Privacy Policy in the foorter, goto Admin panel `CMS > Static Blocks` disable the block with title **Footer Links**.

Now you should get the links in footer. 
If still you doesn't get the links call this `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("footer_links") ?>` in `footer.phtml` file as suggested by **Amit Bera**

**NOTE:** If you are using custom theme then create the `local.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout`